# Making a login script safe using sessions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, authentication

I am currently busy with my own login script that is simple but also safe enough to fit my goal. It uses MySQL to save the usernames and passwords. Now I came to the point of using sessions to be able to check whether a user is logged in, just like it can be found in many tutorials. So far I came up to this, but I'm just not sure whether this is a proper/safe way to do this.

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=HOST;dbname=DATABASE;charset=UTF-8', 
              'USERNAME', 
              'PASSWORD',
              array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
              PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
  $select = $db->prepare("SELECT id, username FROM vwo5_users WHERE username=:username AND password=:password");
  $select->execute(array(':username' => $_POST['username'], ':password' => $_POST['password']));
  $amount = $select->rowCount();
  $result = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $user_id = $result['id'];
  $user_name = $result['username'];


  if($amount >= 1){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user_name;
    echo 'Logged in';
  }
  else{
    echo 'Wrong login data';
  }  
}
else{
    header('Location: dbtestform.php');
}

?>
```

I would then check at a secured page whether the *id* and *username* from the session go together in the database as well, but I can't put my finger on the point of this being safe or not. I know it's being described all over the internet, but no source I found made it more clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I'm just not sure whether this is a proper/safe way to do this.*

Looks fine, but it doesn't appear you're hashing your passwords which you should definitely do. Look into BCrypt.

I don't believe people typically store both the user id and username in the session, just store one or the other and you can query whatever other information you need when a new request is made.

Other than the hashing it looks perfectly fine.

Comment: Yep, I thought about the hashing, but I left it like this for easier testing. I'll use the id in the session then and query the username when I need it. Thanks for approving.